# Meteor js and fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, fullcalendar

I want to resize an event in fullcalendar with meteorjs. I would like to recover the date in the input to set the size. I tried so many things like the next code but it failed.

I would like to format date in "dd-mm-yy" too.

Please also explain how to use alaning role inside my js file to prevent a user from having a click event.

Thanks for your help.

My file .html:

```html
<template name="planning">
 {{#if isInRole 'view-projects,prof,admin'}}
 {{>dialog}}
    <div class="container">
      <div id="calendar">
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="dialog">
<div class="modal" id="EditEventModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close closeDialog" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="">Modification evenment</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Nom du projet</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="" value="{{title}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dateSart">Début:</label>
      <input type="text" name="anniversaire" class="form-control" id="dateStart" placeholder="" value="{{start}}">
    </div>
    <div id="rightDateEnd" class="form-group">
      <label for="dateEnd">Fin:</label>
      <input type="text" name="anniversaire" class="form-control" id="end" placeholder="" value="{{end}}">
    </div>
  </form>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">Delete</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary updateTitle updateDateEnd">Save</a>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default closeDialog" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

my file client.js :

```js
  Template.dialog.events({
    "click .closeDialog": function(event, template){
      Session.set('editing_event', null);
    },
    "click .updateTitle":function(evt, tmpl){
      var title = tmpl.find('#title').value;
      Meteor.call('updateTitle', Session.get('editing_event'),title);
      Session.set('editing_event', null);
      $('#EditEventModal').modal("hide");
    },
    "click .remove":function(evt, tmpl){
      Meteor.call('removeCalEvent', Session.get('editing_event'));
      Session.set('editing_event', null);
      $('#EditEventModal').modal("hide");
    },
    "click .updateStart":function(evt, tmpl){
      var start = tmpl.find('#start').value;
      Meteor.call('updateStart', Session.get('editing_event'),start);
      Session.set('editing_event',null);
    },
    "click .updateEnd":function(evt, tmpl){
      var end = tmpl.find('#end').value;
      Meteor.call('updateEnd', Session.get('editing_event'),end);
      Session.set('editing_event',null);
    }
  });
  Template.planning.helpers({
    editing_event:function()
    {
      return Session.get('editing_event');
    }
  });
  Template.dialog.helpers({
    title:function(){
      var ce = CalEvent.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_event')});
      return ce.title;
    },
    start:function(){
      var ce = CalEvent.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_event')});
      return ce.end;
    },
    end:function(){
      var cend = CalEvent.findOne({_id:Session.get('editing_event')});
      return cend.end;
    }
  });


  Template.dialog.rendered = function()
  {
    if(Session.get('editDialog'))
    {
      var calevent = CalEvent.findOne({_id:Session.get('editDialog')});
      if(calevent)
      {
        $('#title').val(calevent.title);
        $('#start').val(calevent).start;
        $('#end').val(calevent).end;
      }
    }
    $('#end').datepicker();
    $('#dateStart').datepicker();
  }

  Template.planning.rendered = function()
  {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      dayClick:function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
        var calendarEvent = {};
        calendarEvent.start = date;
        calendarEvent.end = date;
        calendarEvent.title = 'Nouveau Projet';
        calendarEvent.owner = Meteor.userId();
        Meteor.call('saveCalEvent', calendarEvent);
      },
      eventClick:function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
        Session.set('editing_event',calEvent._id);
        $('title').val(calEvent.title);
        $('#EditEventModal').modal("show");
      },
      eventDrop:function(reqEvent){
        Meteor.call('moveEvent', reqEvent);
      },
      events:function(start, end, callback){
        var calEvents = CalEvent.find({}, {reactive:false}).fetch();
        callback(calEvents);
      },
      editable:true,
      selectable: true
      formatDate:
    }).data().fullCalendar;
    Deps.autorun(function(){
      CalEvent.find().fetch();
      if(calendar){
        calendar.refetchEvents();
      }
    })
  }
```

my file server.js:

```js
 if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function ()
  {
    Meteor.methods({
      'saveCalEvent':function(ce)
      {
        CalEvent.insert(ce);
      },
      'updateTitle':function(id,title){
        return CalEvent.update({_id:id},{$set:{title:title}});
      },
      'removeCalEvent':function(id,tittle){
        return CalEvent.remove({_id:id});
      },
      'updateStart':function(id,start){
        return CalEvent.update({_id:id},{$set:{start:start}});
      },
      'updateEnd':function(id,end){
        return CalEvent.update({_id:id},{$set:{end:end}});
      },
      'moveEvent':function(reqEvent){
        return CalEvent.update({_id:reqEvent._id},{
          $set:{
            start:reqEvent.start,
            end:reqEvent.end
          }
        })
      }
    })
  });
 }
```

Thx again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I agree. Can't do that with my 36 reputation though.

Answer (score 0):

No where do I see it as a submit event so `event.preventDefault()` shouldn't make a difference. The [Peddle Hawk Blog](http://blog.peddlehawk.com) wrote about using FullCalendar I hope it's more useful: [How to add fullcalendar in meteor](https://blog.peddlehawk.com/how-to-add-fullcalendar-to-your-meteor-project-58101c815641)

Comment: Please explain more in your answers. links are good when you refer to them as extra explanation. answers must be integrity feature.